# Can I guess the size of a shark by the size of its dorsal fin?

Tags: sea, scuba-diving, surfing, sharks

Is there a relative scale to which one can estimate the size of a shark by looking at its dorsal fin?

I know it will differ from species to species, but is there a general guideline maybe for each?

Say a Great White shark with a dorsal fin of 40 cm (1.3 ft).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a general guideline, however I did find a [guide](http://www.fao.org/3/a-i5445e.pdf) by the Food and Agriculture Organization of the United Nations that has the calculations.

The calculations for a Great White are on page 38, and the directions for the calculations start at page 13. I wish I could find a simple rule of thumb, but it looks like there is a good bit of math involved.