# How to scuba dive safely in waters that have Great White Sharks?

Tags: safety, scuba-diving, sharks

This is something I have been thinking about since answering this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/13400/can-i-guess-the-size-of-a-shark-by-the-size-of-its-dorsal-fin) about guessing the size of a shark. What precautions would a scuba diver take or is this something that is simply avoided?

Answer (score 1):

This question is easy! Just dive as you would. If you see a shark, don't dive towards it, because it could think you want to attack. Just stay in one spot, watch the shark, and enjoy!

Sharks are very curious animals, which just want to have a look, and then swim away. The is no need to worry the shark would attack you. Sharks are friendly and don't eat humans.

I dove a bunch of times with different sharks. I even spend 2 Years living on the fidschi islands and doing research about sharks. I saw many sharks of  different kinds. Be ready to be mind-blown by these amazing creatures!

Have fun and a great dive!

Comment: -1: From Wikipedia - "Out of more than 480 shark species, only three are responsible for two-digit numbers of fatal unprovoked attacks on humans: the great white, tiger and bull;[1] " - the question is specifically about GW's, suggesting you just jump in and enjoy without knowledge of shark behaviour is dangerous.

Comment: "two-digit numbers" -- In the realm of accidental death stats that's not even a blip.  Last I read (no I don't have a cite handy) quite a lot of people die hiking and backpacking every year.

Comment: @RussellSteen presumably there are a lot more people hiking and backpacking every year than spending time near those kinds of sharks ?

Comment: @tomfumb -- More people backpacking than swimming in the ocean in warm waters?... hard to believe.  Call me skeptical ;)

Comment: I dive in and around Greater Cape Town area (South Africa) where we have a good number of Great Whites and other sharks. In 2500 dives I have actually seen a GW twice. And i treat them like any other shark, with respect and admiration. I try to stay near the bottom when sharks are around and I never take any kind of food with me in the water. So far with over 500 shark dives I have 0 incidents.

Comment: "Sharks are friendly and don't eat humans." implies they are no more dangerous than rabbits, yet over 2500 people have been attacked and 500 killed in the last 50 years.

Comment: @mattnz I myself dove with a Great White some years ago. And they are, as well as all other sharks, curious. If they don't know that something is, they swim around it, observe it. But as a diver the is no risk if you behave correctly. You throw around with big numbers, but have you researched how many divers were attacked by sharks? Propably none. I'd say that almost all shark attacks are, because some idiot braught a steak or so in the ocean to see sharks. Maybe there were 500 idiots like that in the last 50 years.

Comment: Hi all, take it to chat.

Comment: "sharks dont eat humans"... they are predators, we can be tasty, I dont think they have a rule one way or the other when it comes to us. How many divers? last one I heard was this June, a woman got attacked diving off Perth... diving you have the advantage to not be on the surface the whole time and a tad removed from the hunting spots (drops aside) unlike surfers and swimmers

Comment: "The is no need to worry, the shark would attack you.". Are you aware that the comma reverses the meaning of that sentence, making it mean that the shark would certainly attack you.

Comment: A lot of those shark attacks are actually Surfers. While surfing, they resemble seals when those attacks happen.